# How to apply constant reference parameter on this code?

Tags: c++, class, oop

This code is passing object to a function and I want to apply constant reference parameter on this code.

```
class Test
{
    int num;
public :
    void setNum(int z)
    {
        num=z;
    }//end mutator

    int getNum()
    {
        return num;
    }//end accessor
};//end class
void storeNumber(Test &n)
{
    int a=10;
    n.setNum(a);
}
void displayNumber(Test n)
{
    cout<<"number="<<n.getNum()<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    Test t;
    t.setNum(5);
    cout<<t.getNum()<<endl;
    storeNumber(t);//pass by reference;
    displayNumber(t); //pass by value
    cout<<t.getNum();
}
```

This code is passing object to a function and I want to apply constant reference parameter on this code.
Any help!!

Comment: Where exactly do you want to apply a `const &`?

Comment: So what issue do you face in applying constant reference?

Comment: I got errors when I tried it

Comment: Show erroneous code with error.

Answer (score 1):

You can do for example `void displayNumber(const Test &n)` but then if you call methods of the `Test` class, they must have the `const` qualifier too (for example `int getNum() const`). If you pass `Test` as `const &` to a function, then you won't be able to use `void setNum(int z)` function as it violates the `constant`ness of the class.

## Edit:

Here is the full code:

```
class Test
{
    int num;
public :
    void setNum(int z)
    {
        num=z;
    }//end mutator

    int getNum() const
    {
        return num;
    }//end accessor
};//end class
void storeNumber(Test &n)
{
    int a=10;
    n.setNum(a);
}
void displayNumber(const Test &n)
{
    cout<<"number="<<n.getNum()<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    Test t;
    t.setNum(5);
    cout<<t.getNum()<<endl;
    storeNumber(t);//pass by reference;
    displayNumber(t); //pass by value
    cout<<t.getNum();
}
```

Comment: Ok Can you plz tell me how it will be the code because I tried it I got errors

Comment: I edited the answer to show the full code.

Comment: I tried it but I got errors

Comment: As u said we don't need `void  setNum(int z)`

Comment: But u used it on the edited code

Comment: I didn't say that we don't need it. I meant that you wouldn't be able to use it in `void displayNumber(const Test &n)` function, which I have not.

Comment: Thanks I got it

Comment: @H_D please consider accepting the answer if it is a valid answer to your question. This is important for other people having  the same problem coming here for help.